# Why doesn't std::vector<T> have conversion operator std::span<T,extent>?

Tags: c++, c++20

Considering the `std::string` has (conversion operator) `operator std::string_view`, Why doesn't `std::vector<T>` have `operator std::span<T,extent>`?

What is the underlying reason? Is the `operator std::span<T,extent>` hamful？

Edit: Thanks to NathanOliver. The following code indeed can work

```cpp
void foo(std::span<int> f);
std::vector<int> data;
foo(data);
```

I'm still confused about which form is better? conversion operator or constructor?
std::string and std::string_view show us an example of a conversion operator.
std::vector and std::span (initially named array_view?) show us an example of the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a `std::vector<T>::operator std::span<T,extent>` because `std::span` has the constructor

```
template< class R >
explicit(extent != std::dynamic_extent)
constexpr span( R&& r );
```

Which accepts a `std::vector`.  Here `R` basically needs to be a contiguous range like object.  For full details on the constraints see constructor 7 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span)

You can see your code working in this [live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Vkie8v19IrNsvw4M)

Comment: Thanks. I made mistake. I wrote similar code in a big project. The code can't compile. I addressed the source of the error incorrectly.

Comment: @HarryLeong No problem.  To address your edit, this isn't really a style question.  span was design to be a generic interface for a contiguous data structure.  To facilitate that, it has a constructor that will take anything that satisfies those conditions so the caller of the interface doesn't have add anything to their code.

Comment: My thinking is the inverse of yours. When we convert the special class instance to the general/fundamental class instance. The special class is responsible for the conversion. For example, we have a `struct Arr{ int*Data(); int Len() const; };` only the class knows how to convert it to the general/fundamental object.